# PHP: Getting Final Rendered HTML of a Remote Site

Tags: javascript, php, html

Lets say there's a HTML page with following code in it -

```
<body>
  <div id='some_id'></div>
  <script>
     var div = document.getElementById("some_id");
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     input.type="text";     
     input.value="text box";
     div.appendChild(input); 
 </script>
</body>
```

Now if I do View-source, I will see this above code. But If I use a firebug, I will see this -

```
<body>
  <div id='some_id'><input type="text"></div>
  <script>
     var div = document.getElementById("some_id");
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     input.type="text";     
     input.value="text box";
     div.appendChild(input); 
 </script>
</body>
```

That is, the final rendered HTML output is different. Lets assume this file is on another server like - http://www.someanotherserver.com/some_file.html

Now is it possible in PHP to get the final rendered HTML output ? `file_get_contents` I guess will just show what I see in view-source.

Answer (score 2):

Using PHP, no there is no way you can get the final rendered HTML. This is because the changes made to the original source code are done when the javascript executes. This requires you to have a Javascript engine/runtime (your browser has one).

Doing `file_get_contents()` is the same as doing `curl` or `wget` - it queries the server, but does not execute any JS.

Comment: There is some HTML rendering engine for PHP, you can see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ or http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php

Comment: You can have the javascript execute by introducing a JS runtime. htmlunit seems to be an example. Also look into Selenium - it has some PHP bindings, I believe.